# Invalidating glyphs in TextKit

Tags: ios, layout, ios7, glyph, textkit

I'm attempting to implement a text folding effect to hide some of the text in a UITextView based on attributes in the text storage and then setting those glyph properties to NSGlyphPropertyNull in the `layoutManager: shouldGenerateGlyphs: properties: characterIndexes: font:(UIFont *)aFont forGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange` method. That part is working great so far and does what it's expected to do. The problem is when I try to force the layout manager of the text view to re-layout the text. I've tried calling all of the invalidate methods, but only one works, `invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange: changeInLength: actualCharacterRange:`. I pass in the whole range of characters, 0 for changeInLength since I didn't actually change anything, and NULL for actualCharacterRange. Every once in a while, this works just fine. But most of the time I get this error, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The index -4097 is invalid'`. What is going wrong with this? Here's some of my code surrounding that:

```
-(IBAction)showHideNotes:(id)sender {
    self.hideNotes = !self.hideNotes;
    [self.textView.layoutManager invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:NSMakeRange(0, _textStorage.string.length) changeInLength:0 actualCharacterRange:NULL];
    [self.textView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Basically my goal is that when the user taps a button, the text will either fold or unfold because of that. In the UILayoutManagerDelegate method, `layoutManager: shouldGenerateGlyphs: properties: characterIndexes: font: forGlyphRange:`, I'm setting the glyphs I want hidden to NSGlyphPropertyNull only if `self.hidden` is `YES`

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for [`invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:changeInLength:actualCharacterRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange%3achangeInLength%3aactualCharacterRange%3a):

> This method only invalidates glyph information and performs no glyph generation or layout. Because invalidating glyphs also invalidates layout, **after invoking this method you should also invoke invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange:actualCharacterRange:, passing charRange as the first argument.**

Also make sure that you are honoring the other documented limitation of this method:

> This method is used by the layout mechanism and should be invoked only during typesetting, in almost all cases only by the layout manager. For example, a custom layout manager might invoke it.

When you say that you're setting the glyphs, do you mean you're calling `setGlyphs:properties:characterIndexes:font:forGlyphRange:` inside of the delegate method? Doing that should be sufficient to invalidate the glyphs. ("Calling this method for a character range that has previously calculated layout information invalidates the layout and display.")

Comment: I updated my post to include a bit more information and more where my code is currently. Thanks for the help with the documentation. In fact I am not calling that method right so I'll look into the other ones more.